# TensorFlow EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I am new to Tensorflow. I am making the code listed bellow, but facing the following problem when running it:

> EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was
>   reached

Could anyone help me understand why this occurs ?

The code is below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.__version__)
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(training_images, training_labels), (test_images, test_labels)= mnist.load_data()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(training_images[0])
print(training_labels[0])
print(training_images[0])
training_images = training_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images / 255.0
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)])
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOPtimizer(),
              loss= 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics= ['accuracy'])
model.fit(training_images, training_labels, epochs=5)
model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
```

Comment: Check this one. It should resolve your issue

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877781/eoferror-compressed-file-ended-before-the-end-of-stream-marker-was-reached-mn