# error while loading fashion mnist dataset

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, image-classification

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
fashion_mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

and i am getting this error

```
EOFError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d38ad79b1741> in <module>
      3 fashion_mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
      4 
----> 5 (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\datasets\fashion_mnist.py in load_data()
     82   with gzip.open(paths[1], 'rb') as imgpath:
     83     x_train = np.frombuffer(
---> 84         imgpath.read(), np.uint8, offset=16).reshape(len(y_train), 28, 28)
     85 
     86   with gzip.open(paths[2], 'rb') as lbpath:

~\miniconda3\lib\gzip.py in read(self, size)
    290             import errno
    291             raise OSError(errno.EBADF, "read() on write-only GzipFile object")
--> 292         return self._buffer.read(size)
    293 
    294     def read1(self, size=-1):

~\miniconda3\lib\gzip.py in read(self, size)
    496                 break
    497             if buf == b"":
--> 498                 raise EOFError("Compressed file ended before the "
    499                                "end-of-stream marker was reached")
    500 

EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached
```

on stackoverflow i found a answer that says delete the existing file and download it again but that dosen't work

Comment: the file is corrupted I suggest remove and re install keras. I'm not sure but scikit learn might also have the database.

Comment: it worked i just change the dir path for installation of dataset to something else i don't know why it wasn't working on default directory but thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Happens due to partial download of Dataset . Putting similar issue for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877781/eoferror-compressed-file-ended-before-the-end-of-stream-marker-was-reached-mn