# raise EOFError('Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached')

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, mnist

I am having some trouble in Tensorflow when I try loading data from the fashion_mnist dataset in Keras.

This is my code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras


img = "shoe.png"
mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
predictions = model.predict(img)
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: error may suggests it had problem to download compressed file with data and now it has problem to uncompress it. It may need to download again `fashion_mnist`. Maybe you need better connection with internet.

Comment: here is source code for [load_data](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.10.0/keras/datasets/fashion_mnist.py#L28-L111) and you can see URLs for files which it needs to download - so you can try to download them manually. There is also information in what folder you should put data.

Comment: Hi @Kool, found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46372714/14290697), it could help in resolving this. Thank you!